# Only one alert box, instead of more

Tags: javascript

It's maybe a stupid question, but it's my first year working with something like javascript.
I got some alert boxes, and I was wondering if there any possiblility to show only one alert box (in javascript) with all the stuff I want them to do. 
And when they fill in one of the inputs or buttons, that the allert will only show the other missing things.

(I'm getting an alert of the first code. When I fill it in I get an alert of the next code, and so on. I want to have all in one.)

```
/*validate name*/
var n=document.forms["check"]["name"].value;
if(n==null||n=="")
{
    alert("Please, fill in your name.");
    return false;
}

/*validate the sex*/
if(document.getElementById('male').checked) 
{
} 
else if(document.getElementById('female').checked)
{
} 
else
{
    alert("Please, enter your gender.");
    return false;
}

/*validate the E-mail*/
var e=document.forms["check"]["email"].value;
var atpos=e.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=e.lastIndexOf(".");
if(e==null||e=="")
{
    alert("Please, fill in your e-mail.");
    return false;
}
if(atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=e.length)
{
    alert("This isn't a valid e-mail address.");
    return false;
}

/*validate agreement*/
if(document.getElementById("I don't want my information to be part of this website.").checked) 
{
} 
else if(document.getElementById("I wish to be registered.").checked) 
{
} 
else if(document.getElementById("I wish to get the new content of this website.").checked) 
{
} 
else
{
    alert("Please, tell us what we can do with your information.");
    return false;
}

/*validate the terms*/
if(document.getElementById("yes").checked)
{

}
else if(document.getElementById("no").checked)
{
    alert("You have to agree with the terms.");
    return false;
}
else
{
    alert("Please, enter the terms.");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hello, you should create an global array and join it at the all end :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// initialise an array to populate along the way
var alerts = [];

/*validate name*/
var n = document.forms[ "check" ][ "name" ].value;
if ( n == null || n == "" ) {
    // push message onto the array
    alerts.push( "Please, fill in your name." );
    return false;
}

/*validate the sex*/
if ( document.getElementById( 'male' ).checked ) {} else if ( document.getElementById( 'female' ).checked ) {} else {
    // push message onto the array
    alerts.push( "Please, enter your gender." );
    return false;
}

/*validate the E-mail*/
var e = document.forms[ "check" ][ "email" ].value;
var atpos = e.indexOf( "@" );
var dotpos = e.lastIndexOf( "." );
if ( e == null || e == "" ) {
    // push message onto the array
    alerts.push( "Please, fill in your e-mail." );
    return false;
}
if ( atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= e.length ) {
    // push message onto the array
    alerts.push( "This isn't a valid e-mail address." );
    return false;
}

// join up the array of messages, and alert the user...
alert(alerts.join(", "));
```

### In summary...

```
// initialise an array to populate along the way
var alerts = [];
```

...

```
// push messages onto the array
// (repeat this step for all messages)
alerts.push( "Any validation message" );
```

...

```
// join up the array of messages, and alert the user...
alert(alerts.join(", "));
```

Comment: It works great the only thing is, all the "return false" has to be 1 under the "alerts.join" code. Like this...

Comment: alert(alerts.join(", "));    return false;